# Django URL Conf For Keyword Argument

Tags: django, django-urls

What's wrong with the URL conf below:

```
  url(
                           r'^outgoing-recommendations(?P<entry>\w+)/$',
                           login_required(outgoing_messages),
                           name='outgoing-recommendations',
                       ),
```

Here is the invocation:

```
return redirect('outgoing-recommendations', kwargs={'entry':'outgoing'})
```

Here is the view function:

```
def outgoing_messages(request,entry):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.session['user_id'])
```

I'm getting the error below:

Reverse for 'outgoing-recommendations' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'entry': 'outgoing'}}' not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should look like this

```
url(r'^outgoing-recommendations/(?P<entry>\w+)/$',login_required(outgoing_messages), name='outgoing-recommendations'),
```

So you forgot your `/` on outgoing-recommendations.

Also you should call your `redirect` like this

```
return redirect('outgoing-recommendations', entry='outgoing')
```

and leave off the `kwargs={}` part, because what's happening is that you're trying to send in the keyworded arguments `kwargs` with it's nested kwargs.

But what I think you actually want is this

```
return redirect(reverse('outgoing-recommendations', kwargs={'entry':'outgoing'}))
```